# Rendering camera into multiple surfaces - on and off screen

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I want to render the camera output into a view and once in a while save the camera output frame to a file, with the constraint being - the saved frame should be the **same resolution** as the camera is configured, while the view is **smaller than the camera output** (maintaining the aspect ratio).

Based on the [ContinuousCaptureActivity example in grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java), I thought the best approach would be to send the camera to a `SurfaceTexture` and generally rendering the output and downscaling it into a `SurfaceView`, and when needed, render the full frame into a different `Surface` that has no view, in order to retrieve a byte buffer from it in parallel to the regular `SurfaceView` rendering.

The example is very similar to my situation - the preview is rendered to a view of smaller size and can be recorded and saved at the full resolution via a `VideoEncoder`.

I replaced the `VideoEncoder` logic with my own and got stuck trying to provide a `Surface`, like the encoder does, for the full resolution rendering. How do I create such a `Surface`? Am I approaching this correctly?

---

Some code ideas based on the example:

---

Inside the `surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)` method (line 350):

```
@Override   // SurfaceHolder.Callback
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated holder=" + holder);

    mEglCore = new EglCore(null, EglCore.FLAG_RECORDABLE);
    mDisplaySurface = new WindowSurface(mEglCore, holder.getSurface(), false);
    mDisplaySurface.makeCurrent();

    mFullFrameBlit = new FullFrameRect(
            new Texture2dProgram(Texture2dProgram.ProgramType.TEXTURE_EXT));
    mTextureId = mFullFrameBlit.createTextureObject();
    mCameraTexture = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureId);
    mCameraTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

    Log.d(TAG, "starting camera preview");
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mCameraTexture);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
    }
    mCamera.startPreview();


    // *** MY EDIT START ***

    // Encoder creation no longer needed
    //  try {
    //    mCircEncoder = new CircularEncoder(VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT, 6000000,
    //            mCameraPreviewThousandFps / 1000, 7, mHandler);
    //  } catch (IOException ioe) {
    //      throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
    //  }

    mEncoderSurface = new WindowSurface(mEglCore, mCameraTexture); // <-- Crashes with EGL error 0x3003

    // *** MY EDIT END ***

    updateControls();
}
```

The `drawFrame()` method (line 420):

```
private void drawFrame() {
    //Log.d(TAG, "drawFrame");
    if (mEglCore == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Skipping drawFrame after shutdown");
        return;
    }

    // Latch the next frame from the camera.
    mDisplaySurface.makeCurrent();
    mCameraTexture.updateTexImage();
    mCameraTexture.getTransformMatrix(mTmpMatrix);

    // Fill the SurfaceView with it.
    SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.continuousCapture_surfaceView);
    int viewWidth = sv.getWidth();
    int viewHeight = sv.getHeight();
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    mFullFrameBlit.drawFrame(mTextureId, mTmpMatrix);
    mDisplaySurface.swapBuffers();

    // *** MY EDIT START ***

    // Send it to the video encoder.
    if (someCondition) {
        mEncoderSurface.makeCurrent();
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        mFullFrameBlit.drawFrame(mTextureId, mTmpMatrix);
        mEncoderSurface.swapBuffers();
        try {
            mEncoderSurface.saveFrame(new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // *** MY EDIT END ***

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track.  The SurfaceTexture just does a quick bit of wrapping around the original YUV frame from the camera, so the "external" texture is the original image, with no changes.  You can't read the pixels straight out of an external texture, so you have to render it somewhere first.

The easiest way to do this is to create an off-screen pbuffer surface.  Grafika's gles/OffscreenSurface class does exactly this (with a call to `eglCreatePbufferSurface()`).  Make that EGLSurface current, render the texture onto a FullFrameRect, then read the framebuffer with `glReadPixels()` (see `EglSurfaceBase#saveFrame()` for code).  Don't call `eglSwapBuffers()`.

Note that you're not creating an Android Surface for the output, just an EGLSurface.  ([They're different](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#eglsurface).)

Comment: Thanks, it works. I've been reading about pbuffers and as far as I understand, they are not very efficient, and working with FBOs or PBOs is much better. Is that true in this regard?

Comment: If you were working with a regular 2D texture, you could set the texture as the color buffer for an FBO, and read the pixels straight out of it. However, an "external" texture can't be used this way (remember that the camera output is YUV, while GLES works with RGB), so you have to render the texture somewhere first before you can read it back with `glReadPixels()`. My experience on Android has been that 95+% of the time will be spent compressing and saving the image, with most of the rest going to `glReadPixels()`, and any inefficiency w.r.t. pbuffer will be in the noise.